# Migrate NFTables settings to other machines

Tags: linux, firewall

I'm looking for a solution to migrate my NFTables settings automatically on a day to day basis to other linux computers in my network. I was thinking about writing a script to pull the settings from my computer and somehow overwrite the old nftables.conf file on the other computer(B) in the network. Computer B would execute the script via cron every day.
At least that's my initial thought since i couldn't find any tools that can do this on their own.
Am i missing the point here, is it even possible the way i want to do it or are there already solutions for this task?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can export or store your current ruleset in a file using `export`/`list` command then you can import that  ruleset file using `-f` option.

For Example:

`$ nft list ruleset > your_nftables_ruleset_file`

and then

`$ nft -f your_nftables_ruleset_file`

For more info, you can refer this nftables wiki page:
https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Operations_at_ruleset_level

Alternatively, you can export and import ruleset in json format using
`$ nft export vm json > rules.json` and  then`$ cat rules.json | nft import vm json` **(Note: This feature is yet come in mainline)** If you are curious you can use this patch https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/netfilter-devel/list/?series=16814 :)